# Question has gone, can't find it, can't see it, don't know, where did it go?

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, specific-question

Yesterday I asked, [PHP langauge barrier design problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774899/php-langauge-barrier-design-problem) on Stack Overflow and I cannot seem to find it anymore.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: It says you deleted it.

Comment: Then why would I come here wondering where it went? I went to sleep after leaving a comment.

Comment: Oh right, because nobody ever in the history of computers has ever clicked the wrong button.  I guess Jeff Atwood should deliver a personal apology to you for recording the deletion as "deleted by LiraNuna" even though you couldn't possibly have done it.  It was probably Ninjas.

Comment: I am not seeking someone to blame, I just want the question restored.

Comment: Definitely ninjas. They steal your socks from the dryer too. They need them so they can sneak around so quietly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been stated - it says

> deleted by LiraNuna 13 hours ago

If anybody else had deleted it (including ♦ mods) it would show another person's name. I doubt that somebody has hacked the site *just* to delete your post, so:

- could somebody else have used your computer/session?
- perhaps you simply clicked the wrong button? (it happens...)

Let me know if you want it undeleted (assuming this option isn't available to you, or you would have clicked it already).

Comment: he has almost 4k reps, he should be able to do it, right?

Comment: Please undelete it, I didn't delete it nor want it deleted.

Comment: @Amargosh: I cannot undelete it myself.

Comment: Done... now undeleted